# Naive Bayes: Understanding the Entropy equation

Tags: naive-bayes, entropy

I am trying to understand the entropy equation:

```
-p1*log2(p1) - p2*log2(p2) - pn*log2(pn)
```

Specifically why do we multiply each log by the probability? In the tutorial from Udacity, they begin explaining how we originally multiply each of the probabilities:

```
p1 * p2 * ... * pn
```

But since the product of many terms can leave us with a very small number, we sub in logs (and reverse sign since p < 1) - ok, cool.

So we should have:

```
- log2(p1) - log2(p2) - ... - log2(pn)
```

Why do we then multiply each log term by its probability, e.g. -**p1**log2(p1)?

Does it have to do with weighting the terms?

Thank you!

Comment: I've found that the 1st chapter of "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" by Bishop does a good job at motivating the formula for entropy: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/55881.Pattern_Recognition_and_Machine_Learning

Comment: Thank you @ValentinWaeselynck . Might you be able to paraphrase the specific section here for other viewers and so I can mark the answer correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to motivate the entropy formula is to interpret each of the $-log_2(p_i)$ terms as the amount of 'surprise' or 'gained information' yielded by observing outcome $i$.

The idea is 'surprise' of observing 2 i.i.d variables should be the sum of the 'surprise' for each variable, should be positive, and should be a function of the probability, hence the negated logarithm.

Entropy is then just the expectation of this 'surprise' term, hence the $p_i$ factor.

Comment: Nice. Josh Starmer from StatQuest explained entropy using Surprise too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YtebGVx-Fxw